# How to block an empty user agent request

Tags: .htaccess

Is there any solution for preventing http request that has an empty user agent string preferably using .htaccess?

Answer (score 2):

```
#redirect empty user agent, UNLESS it's accessing the RSS feed
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^$ 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/rss.php # <-- path to rss.php
RewriteRule .* http://%{REMOTE_ADDR}/ [R,L]
```

Archived Source: [http://wiki.e107.org/index.php?title=Htaccessexample](https://web.archive.org/web/20150921041636/http://wiki.e107.org/index.php?title=Htaccessexample)

Comment: I like how this redirects the traffic back to the potential attacker's own computer. 

Comment: Well I have not known this but that is funny 